# How to change limit of selected data in MYSQL PHP.?

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tabs with its content. content is records, coming from the MySQL table.

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-nostyle" id="tabnavBar" style="border-top: thin solid #000000; border-bottom: thin solid #000000; ">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" id="tab1" href="#tab1"  style="border-right: thin solid #000000;">Tab 1 <img src="assets/images/infoico.png" width="20" height="20"></a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="pill" id="tab2" href="#tab2" style="border-right: thin solid #000000;">Tab 2 <img src="assets/images/infoico.png" width="20" height="20"></a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="pill" id="tab3" href="#tab3"  style="border-right: thin solid #000000;">Tab 3 <img src="assets/images/infoico.png" width="20" height="20"> </a></li>                                
</ul>
```

How can I store my content in this three tabs with limited row.

first is 0-9.
second is 10-19.
Third is 20-29.

I am just trying simple data retrieve query.

```
<?php $sql = "select * from datab limit 0,9"

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
  {
          echo $row;
  }
?>
```

How can I use this `$sql` for other two tabs.

Comment: adjust the limit ?

Comment: You yourself are using `limit 0,9` in your query. Adapt that to what chunk of data you are interested in.

Comment: How.? When I change tabs the limit  also should change. and I want to keep first tabs records as it is when retrieve.

Comment: just add 10 to the first number in the LIMIT clause: `select * from datab limit 0,10` for page 1, `select * from datab limit 10,10` for page 2, `select * from datab limit 20,10` for page 3 etc...

Comment: OK  I understand, got it.

Comment: you can do that using single query , make this in php end ..............

Comment: check my answer so you can manage it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this code

```
<?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "test";
 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  $sql = "SELECT  * FROM user";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 // output data of each row
$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($i < 10){
        $row1[] = $row;
    } else if($i > 9 && $i < 19){
       $row2[] = $row;
   } else {
    $row3[] = $row;
}
$i++;
}

}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($row1);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($row2);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($row3);
?>
```

you can also do that using mysql every select option use separate query

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM datab LIMIT 10"; // for show 10 rows
```

and next 10 rows

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM datab LIMIT 10,10"; // for  10 - 20 rows
```

and last 10 rows

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM datab order by id desc limit"; // for show 10 rows where id your primary key or also
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM datab  limit 20,10";
```

Comment: Should be using the SQL `LIMIT` clause and the offset

Comment: why negative vote? is not working ? please explain it

Comment: i know but if i use this then which problem? use single query and i also know that offset and limit

Comment: just explain is not working? if i use single query and manage in php end so which problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just add 10 in the LIMIT-clause for each page/tab you need:

```
// TAB 1:       
select * from datab limit 0,10

// TAB 2:
select * from datab limit 10,10

//TAB 3:
select * from datab limit 20,10
```

The first number specifies the offset (the first row to return), and the second specifies the max number of rows to return: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp